how do I remove old/residual kernel packages?
After doing a release upgrade from 22.04 -> 24.04, I've got about 200 packages of the name "linux-{image, modules, modules-extra}" that dpkg says are present.
If I grep on ii for the installed ones, I get what I would expect, the current one plus the other associated packages:
root@lwobker-nuc:/home/lwobker# dpkg -l | grep '^ii  linux-'
ii  linux-base                             4.5ubuntu9                               all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                         20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.2          amd64        Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                          6.8.0-41.41                              amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-6.8.0-41                 6.8.0-41.41                              all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.8.0
   << snip for brevity, this is maybe 15-20 lines >>
ii  linux-tools-6.8.0-41                   6.8.0-41.41                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0-41
ii  linux-tools-6.8.0-41-generic           6.8.0-41.41                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0-41
ii  linux-tools-common                     6.8.0-41.41                              all          Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0

without blasting you fine people with 150 lines of text, there are a TON of packages that appear have been removed but not TOTALLY cleaned up...
root@lwobker-nuc:/home/lwobker# dpkg -l | grep '^rc  linux-' | wc
    155    2071   23085
root@lwobker-nuc:/home/lwobker# dpkg -l | grep '^rc  linux-' | head -5
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic          4.15.0-47.50                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-100-generic         5.15.0-100.110                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic         5.15.0-101.111                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-102-generic         5.15.0-102.112                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-105-generic         5.15.0-105.115                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic

I'd like to get these cleaned/purged/removed (I don't know the proper verb here in APT-speak).
I've tried just about every combination of apt clean, purge, remove, autoremove, autoremove-with-purge, apt -fy, and so on.  Nothing so far has seemed to destroy the zombies.
Help?  ;-)
